# What metrics does fabric push to statsd/prometheus?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Fabric has [metrics](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/operations_service.html?highlight=statsd#metrics) feature which can be enabled to gather metrics about the running network. What metrics are published by Fabric on these medium?

I want to gather system metrics.

Is this possible with this feature as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No system resource metrics cannot be obtained.

There is a [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/metrics_reference.html) in the documentation which lists all the metrics for statsd as well as prometheus.